# Voice recognition of just 1 word

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

New to Raspberry Pi - I want to create a device which upon hearing a particular word it will activate/deactivate something.  E.g. if I say the word "light", it will turn on/off an LED light.  The device will only recognize this one and only word that I program it with.  Hoping to use it at home which might have some background noise.

The key part that I'm not sure how to implement is the voice recognition.  Would open-source libraries like mycroft and jasper help with this, or is there any other solution?  If I were to use it in a home setting with various background noises is rnnnoise the state-of-the-art noise cancelling technique or are the open-source packages enough?

Edit: Sorry I should've specified, I want this device to be disconnected from the internet, so using Alexa / Google would be off the table.

Comment: how will the device know that you are giving it a command?

Answer (score 1):

I think the next links can help you:

https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-control-the-raspberry-pi-with-your-voice

https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/build-raspberry-pi-voice-control-for-home-automation/

It explains how to implement voice recognition with the help of Google Voice Commands.

About background noises, I have experimented at work the Google solutions, and it's really a big issue... When your commands can be delayed, you can filter the noises like explained here (https://www.techsmith.com/blog/not-late-reduce-audio-noise-recordings-free/) but sure , it's not easy :)

Comment: You should include the important content in your answer, so that it remains useful even if the links are gone.

Comment: Hello @DmitryGrigoryev, I have a similar project forcasted. 
As you sugest, I will prepare a full reply so, effectively, if the links are gone, nothing will be lost :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Installation of latest Pocketsphinx 5prealpha

Install ALSA and other sound card utilities

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils bison libasound2-dev -y
```

Install Sphinx-base

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/5prealpha/sphinxbase-5prealpha.tar.gz/download -O sphinxbase.tar.gz
tar -xzvf sphinxbase.tar.gz
cd sphinxbase-5prealpha
./configure --enable-fixed
make clean all
sudo make install
```

Install Pocketsphinx

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-5prealpha.tar.gz/download -O pocketsphinx.tar.gz
tar -xzvf pocketsphinx.tar.gz
cd ..
cd pocketsphinx-5prealpha
./configure
make
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib 
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Testing in the **terminal**

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes
```

Example code

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech

trigger = "hey chloe"
speech = LiveSpeech(lm=False, keyphrase='forward', kws_threshold=1e+20)

for phrase in speech:
    tts = phrase.segments(detailed=True)
    print(tts)
    if tts == trigger:
       triggered = True

    while triggered==True:
        tts = phrase.segments(detailed=True)
        print(tts)
        if tts == "light on" or tts == "lights on":
        # turn lights on here
            triggered = False
        elif saying == "light off" or saying == "lights off":
        # turn light off here
            triggered = False
```

Documentation for setup of [CMUSphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/raspberrypi)

Comment: What are Sphinx-base and Pocketsphinx? Can you please elaborate a bit? Where do you get it? With `apt list sphinxbase pocketsphinx` I get pocketsphinx being in the default Raspbian repository. Why do you suggest to compile everything from source and not just install it from the repository?

Comment: Just a simple ```pip install pocketsphinx``` should be used for regular Windows,Linux, or Mac os. Sphinx-base is for other modules and Pocketsphinx to get it to work. Pocketsphinx is a lightweight speech-recognition engine for small devices.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the information there. But you still not answered why not to use `pocketsphinx` from the repository. Just doing a `sudo apt install pocketsphinx` should do the thing and you have a configured installation out of the box.